# Differentiation of Rodrigues' formula

Tags: polynomials, elementary-functions, legendre-polynomials

Iam trying to differentiate Rodrigues' formula m times with respect to x. 
[image: Rodrigues' formula]

to attain the form
[image]

Any help ?

Comment: The m-th derivative of $P_l$ cannot be equal to $P_l^m$. The factors $(-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}$ should not be there.

Comment: ideed this is the problem i faced .. but i found it in all sites in this form .. if it did not come from Rodrigues' formula,  from where it comes ??

Answer (score 2):

The polynomials $P_l^m$ are the [associated Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials),
whereas $P_l$ are Legendre polynomials. The formula you gave are their definitions. $P_l^m$ is defined as in the formula, these polynomials are *not* the m-th derivatives (or powers or whatever) of $P_l$.